Validation XML signature error: Referenced ID is not in DOM document
I am attempting to sign an XML document using a PFX certificate in C#, but I am facing challenges with validating the XML signature. I'm not very experienced in this area and would appreciate your assistance.
When I try to validate the signed XML in XML ValidatorBuddy, I receive the following error message:

Unable to start verification of signature: Referenced ID is not in DOM document.

I also checked on Chilkat Tools:
Signature is Invalid
Number of Reference Digests = 6
Reference 1 digest is valid.
Reference 2 digest is valid.
Reference 3 digest is valid.
Reference 4 digest is valid.
Reference 5 digest is valid.
Reference 6 digest is valid.

I believe that all the IDs are correctly referenced in the document. However, I suspect the issue may be related to the Canonicalization method.
In the provided example XML from the receiver, I noticed the following:
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsa ns soapenv"/>
</ds:CanonicalizationMethod>

However, in my XML, I only have:
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>

I have tried various approaches to resolve this, but I still cannot get the signature validated successfully. Could this be an issue with the Canonicalization process?
This is my sign code:
     public string SignSoapMessageVersion3(string soapRequest, X509Certificate2 certificate, RSA privateKey)
     {

        if(privateKey==null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("private key is nul");
        }

        // Load the SOAP request into an XML document
        XmlDocument soapEnvelope = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelope.PreserveWhitespace = true; // Preserve whitespace
        soapEnvelope.LoadXml(soapRequest);

        SignedXmlWithId signedXml = new SignedXmlWithId(soapEnvelope);
        signedXml.SigningKey = privateKey;

        AddReferencesToSignedXml(signedXml);
        KeyInfo keyInfo = AddKeyInfoPFX(certificate, soapEnvelope);
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";
        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

        // Export the XML document to inspect the ID before signing
        string xmlBeforeSigning = soapEnvelope.OuterXml;
        string documentsFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        string filePathBeforeSigning = Path.Combine(documentsFolderPath, "soap_message_before_signing.xml");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePathBeforeSigning, xmlBeforeSigning);


        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        XmlElement signatureElement = signedXml.GetXml();
        signatureElement.SetAttribute("Id", "Signature-1");
        SetPrefix("ds", signatureElement);

        // Load modified signature back
        signedXml.LoadXml(signatureElement);

        // this is workaround for overcoming a bug in the library
        signedXml.SignedInfo.References.Clear();

        // Recompute the signature
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        string recomputedSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(signedXml.SignatureValue);

        // Replace value of the signature with recomputed one
        ReplaceSignature(signatureElement, recomputedSignature);

        // Insert the signature into the SOAP envelope
        InsertSignatureIntoEnvelope(soapEnvelope, signatureElement);

        string signedSoapRequest;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(streamWriter);
            soapEnvelope.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
            xmlTextWriter.Flush();

            signedSoapRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }

        return signedSoapRequest;
    }

Please help me resolve this issue. I hope I have given enough information.
